# Jquery hide siblings of all li's but toggle siblings of the one being clicked

Tags: jquery

So I've been trying to find a way to hide all the siblings of my list items, except the one which is being clicked. The siblings of the list item being clicked should however be toggled.

My code:

HTML

```
<li class="sample">
   <div class="simple"></div>
   <div class="details"></div>
</li>
<li class="sample">
   <div class="simple"></div>
   <div class="details"></div>
</li>
```

jQuery

```
$('.simple').click(function(){
$('.simple').not(this).siblings('.details').hide();
$(this).siblings('.details').toggle();
});
```

Can't seem to make this work as siblings of the list item being click seem to dissapear and reappear?

Hope you can help!

thanks

Phill

Comment: The list item which has been clicked should be display on every click on it? Or it should be shown on first click then should hide on second click and so on....

Comment: it should be shown on first click and then hidden on the second (toggled). while all the other list items remain hidden.

Comment: So what change you want in your script in that case your script is working fine.

Comment: it doesn't for me though :/ when I click on the list item the "details" div does not become visible

Comment: The "details" of the list item being clicked are shown and then hidden again in a sinlge click

Answer (score -1):

Instead of [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), use [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

```js
$('.simple').click(function(){
    $('.simple').not($(this)).siblings('.details').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.details').show();
});
```

```css
.simple,
.details {
   display: block;
      height: 100px;
 }
 
 .simple {
   background: #ff00ff;
 }
 
 .details {
   background: blue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="sample">
   <div class="simple"></div>
   <div class="details"></div>
</li>
<li class="sample">
   <div class="simple"></div>
   <div class="details"></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah, but I would like the "details" of the list item being clicked to be hidden again on the second click, show on 3. hidden on 4. etc....

This way it is just shown until you click an other list item